# How to sum sales data by year

Tags: powerbi

[current visualisation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDo1Y.png)

Hi im trying to sum by the individual years instead of having so many rows (2014,2015,2016) and end up with only three rows)

The two tables, sales and calendar, are related by Order date ( dd/mm/yy hh) and year (yyyy) respectively.

is there an error with my data for it to turn out like this?

datasets:
[table for calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4cEK.png) //
[Table for salesAmount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTZyU.png)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Year, sum(SalesAmount) FROM table GROUP BY Year

Comment: Do i do this via the query editor? the data are in two different tables. do i have to add a sales column to the calendar data table?

Sorry im still pretty new to this.

Comment: These answer needs to be more redacted. Add at least some explanations on the keywords used in the query. On top of that, it's an uncomplete/incorrect answer as OP has stated that there is two tables involved, so the query should include a junction for the two mentioned tables. I suggest you to edit accordingly the answer.